# Cocoa. Why app's image are changed from png to tiff format in sandbox?

Tags: cocoa, png, sandbox, tiff

my app's resources are png format,but when I run the app,and open the sandbox's content resources directory,I found that all the images in png format are changed to tiff format,how is it going?

anyone could help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like you have the "Combine High Resolution Artwork" setting set in your project's build settings. With this option set Xcode will automatically combine a standard and @2x image into a single TIFF. See [this Apple doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/Optimizing/Optimizing.html) for details.